Procedure of filling WordPress global $wp_the_query
I wanna know how do_action( 'template_redirect' ); is filling up:

[queried_object] => WP_Term Object
    (
        [term_id] => 43
        [name] => media
        [slug] => media
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 42
        [taxonomy] => category
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
        [cat_ID] => 43
        [category_count] => 0
        [category_description] => 
        [cat_name] => media
        [category_nicename] => media
        [category_parent] => 0
    ) 


in global $wp_the_query
if ( wp_using_themes() ) {
    /**
     * Fires before determining which template to load.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    echo "checking global before in template_redirect";
global $wp_the_query;
print_r($wp_the_query);
echo "checking global before in template_redirect";


    do_action( 'template_redirect' );

    echo "checking global after template_redirect ";
    print_r($wp_the_query);
    echo "checking global after template_redirect ";
}

I printed the query one before and one after the do_action( 'template_redirect' );. Removing do_action( 'template_redirect' ); empties $wp_the_query->queried_object

Sorry, but your question is unclear… What are you really trying to achieve? We expect you to provide the code where you are trying $wp_the_query->queried_object in your question, with better details and explanations.

When wordpress runs it needs to figure out what to show on the screen this is controlled by something called $wp_the_query

Before template_redirect: $wp_the_query starts to gather information about what is should show, like a category or post, but its not finished yet.
do_action('template_redirect'): This is a command that tells Wordpress, "finish preparing everything before showing the page", It helps fill in missing details in $wp_the_query, especially the part called queried_object.
After template_redirect: Now $wp_the_query has everything is needs, like which category to show, if you remove this step $wp_the_query->queried_object might stay empty or incomplete.

So that action is very important because it makes sure Wordpress is ready to show the right thing on the screen

yeah, but in which file can i see the whole thing going on or things related to filling $wp_the_query->queried_object

You wold need to look at several key files within the worpress core, The most related files are: 1. wp-includes/class-wp-query.php check this method get_queried_object, 2. wp-includes/query.php, 3. wp-includes/template-loader.php 4. wp-includes/theme.php, 5. wp-includes/functions.php
